# laravel file array storage

Tags: php, arrays, file, laravel

I want to store the file array but i have some problem,this is my html code

```
<div>
<input type="file" name tmp[]></input>
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<input type="file" name tmp[]></input>
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
</div>
```

and my controller

```
foreach ($request->input('text') as $key => $step){
$data = new Step;
if($request->hasFile('tmp[$key]'){
$file = $request->tmp[$key];
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file_name = strval(time()).str_random(5).'.'.$extension;

    $destination_path = public_path().'/step-upload/';
    $data->img_url = $file_name;
    $upload_success = $file->move($destination_path, $file_name);

}
$data->text=$step;
```

but it didn't work, i find out that api didn't support hasFile(array),it only support hasFile( string $key)

and also i remove if($request->hasFile('tmp[$key]'){} but find out that no matter how many input file in there,it only catch the first one. 
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Asuming your HTML is actually correct and that your using the correct enctype on your `form`.*

Laravel uses its dot annotation function in the `hasFile` function. So what you want to do is to use `('tmp.' . $key)` instead of `'tmp[$key]'` (which is incorrect, [read up opon double vs single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/397195)).

So, your code should look like this:

```
foreach ($request->input('text') as $key => $step) {
    if ($request->hasFile('tmp.' . $key)) {
        $file = $request->file('tmp.' . $key);
        // work with $file
    }
}
```